# how to determine if selected date and time is within the range of the duration

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

> How to check if my selected date and time is within the duration (it is the minutes)?

Here's my code:

```
function checkTimeDate(){
    $time = $this->input->post("time", true);

    $this->db->select("time, duration");
    $this->db->from("timetable");
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $message = array();
    $timeConverted = strtotime($time);

            foreach($query->result() as $row){
                if($timeConverted == $row->time){
                    $message = array(
                        "message" => "Please pick another date and time"
                    );
                }else{
                    $message = array(
                        "message" => "Available"
                    );
                }
            }


    $this->output->set_output(json_encode($message));
}
```

In that logic, Im just checking if the selected time and date is equal to the value in my database. I want to add a duration. thanks in advance.

Comment: What are your problems with this code. What errors did you get?

Comment: i dont have error with that code. I want to add a condition that will check if the selected time and date is within the range of the duration.  I have a time column that holds the time and date while the duration column holds the additional minutes(or endTime). example, in my time column, i have jul 1, 2004 9:00 (converted in timestamp) and my duration column is 30mins. if the user select same month, day, year, hour but different minutes, but id the minutes is within the duration, it shoukd display not available.

Comment: Why not convert the dates into DateTime objects, then you can use the diff function

Comment: I tried that already. instead of  $timeConverted = strtotime($time);, I did  $timeConverted = date("m/d/y h:i", strtotime($time)); but it doesnt work because the data in my database is in timestamp

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for something like this:

```
if $timeConverted >= $row->time && $timeConverted <= $ row->time + $row->duration
```

Comment: not working. thanks though. I think i need to seperate the minutes from $row->time. because $row->time is the m/d/y and h:m. I just dont know if that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from("tbl_name");
    $this->db->where("now() >= DATE_SUB(selected_date,INTERVAL 30 DAY)");
```